# Gedit Shortcuts stopped working

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit, shortcuts

Suddenly the Gedit shortcuts stopped working.
For example, Ctrl+F, instead of finding a string makes the cursor to the next character.
Ctrl+H now has the same functionality as backspace.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling gedit, removing plugins, removing preference files etc, but nothing has worked.

Has anybody experienced the same issue? If so, what is the solution? I am using Precise Pangolin, everything is updated to their latest verions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Founnd this problem solved on the Ubuntu Forums site at [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866963)

To summarise, in gnome-tweak-tool the keybinding theme was set to "Emacs" in gnome-tweak-tool. Switched it to "Default" and everything works.

Comment: Have this problem now with linux mint 17, unfortunately gnome-tweak-tool already shows "Default", and switching it to "Emacs" and back still doesn't fix gedit :(

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with linux mint 17. The default key theme seems to be Emacs there, but almost no other tool than gedit care about that (which makes it look like a gedit problem, but it isn't. It's just that linux has become a config spaghetti).

The solution is twofold:
the key *gtk-key-theme* has to be changed from "Emacs" to "Default" in both GConf (the old config system of gnome) and DConf (the new one). You can access GConf via *gconf-editor* and DConf via the linux mint settings dialogs, or directly via *gsettings*.

1. Open Linux Mint's *System Settings* -> *Themes* -> *Other Settings*. Here, switch the drop-down menu *Keybindings* to *Default*, and close the settings dialog. Don't ask me why this setting is in "Themes", and not "Keyboard". Brain fart.
   This should have done it for gedit. Alternative route is using the command *gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme Default*
2. However, The gnome developers who made DConf aren't smart enough to synchronize backward compatible settings with GConf. So open gconf-editor (and this is what the *gnome-tweak-tool* mentioned in Tingting's answer also accesses) and navigate to desktop->gnome->interface. There you'll also find the key *gtk_key_theme*, which you now also set to "Default".

That should be it. What a beautiful example of miserable design and defaults (Emacs-keys as default system wide? seriously? Because Emacs users are so bad at changing configs to their needs?)

Adding some keywords for google: gedit CTRL+F control F doesn't search find work moves cursor forward CTRL+H control H doesn't replace work deletes character